# Is there any link between exotic R4s and Hilbert spaces

Tags: differential-geometry, hilbert-spaces

My question is no more than the title...
That is:
Any mathematical link of any kind between exotic or fake R4s and Hilbert spaces?
Please be kind enough to vulgarize your answer, as I am not a professional mathematician...
Cheers

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Do you have any reason to expect one?